# Can't open mailbox: Invalid remote specification

Tags: php, imap

I need to write a PHP script to get emails from our exchange server. When trying to get them I'm getting this error: Can't open mailbox: invalid remote specification. At the moment I'm using PHP 5.3.29

I've already tried some URL parameter like 'ssl', 'notls' and 'novalidate-cert' for the imap_open() function.

My PHP code:

```
$request_body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$mailbox = $request_body->mailbox;
$username = $request_body->username;
$password = $request_body->password;

$imapResource = imap_open('{'.$mailbox.'}Inbox', $username, $password);

if($imapResource === false){
    echo imap_last_error();
    throw new Exception(imap_last_error());
}
```

My data:

```
{
    "mailbox": "https://xxxx:32000",
    "username": "xxxx@xx.de",
    "password": "xxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "https://" from the "mailbox": "https://xxxx:32000". Ensure that the port number is correct. Typically imap is 993 (SSL) or 143.